# Customising a Bootstrap 3 input-control

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to build a contact form like this one in the image; whats the best way to get input-controls in Bootstrap 3?

I can't manage to make my form label squares and aligned like the ones in the picture.

[image: designed form I'm trying to reproduce]

This is my current code:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 sub-text">
                <h1>
                    Contato
                </h1>
                <hr>
                <p>
                    Se deseja falar conosco, envie uma mensagem
                </p>
            </div><!-- end col -->
            <div class="col-sm-1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name"></label>
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nome">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email"></label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="phone"></label>
                        <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Telefone">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleTextarea"></label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="5" placeholder="Mensagem" ></textarea>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
            </div>
        </div><!-- end row -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 footer-text">
            <p>
                    Copyright © 2015 . Todos os direitos reservados.
            </p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</footer>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hn0agryx/1/)

Comment: Just post the current code. We can help to improve your tried code. Otherwise this post is vulnerable to down votes.

Comment: just added, sorry missed that part, dunno how to put it on Fiddle tho..

Comment: You can always customise your bootstrap  -> http://getbootstrap.com/customize/, unless it's the only form which is different on a whole website. Post your relative css as well.

Comment: Should be close to what you need, just amend the colours for your needs -> https://jsfiddle.net/hn0agryx/2/

Comment: I'm sure you've already posted the same question earlier this morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusted your code to try and replicate the output in the image.

1. Override the default `border-radius` applied to the Bootstrap form fields and text-area.
2. Use a custom margin class to create equal spacing and alignment.
3. Adjust the width of the input fields to occupy the exact space as shown in your output image. Instead of using `col-sm-1` to create horizontal space, use `col-sm-offset-*` class to provide that.

```css
footer .form-inline .form-control,
footer .form-group textarea {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.vertical-offset-15 {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.vertical-offset-5 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
input {
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 sub-text">
        <h1>
                Contato
            </h1>
        <hr>
        <p>
          Se deseja falar conosco, envie uma mensagem
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- end col -->

      <div class="col-sm-6 vertical-offset-5">
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
          <div class="form-group vertical-offset-15">
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Nome">
          </div>
        </form>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
          <div class="form-group vertical-offset-15">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </form>
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">
          <div class="form-group vertical-offset-15">
            <label for="phone"></label>
            <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Telefone">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleTextarea"></label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="5" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- end row -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 footer-text">
        <p>
          Copyright © 2015 . Todos os direitos reservados.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container -->
</footer>
```

Comment: thats just perfect! thanks alot ! is there a way to recolor the border of the labels? Tried using border-color but I guess its not like that... thanks again!

Comment: `footer .form-inline .form-control { border-color: colorname; }` will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is create custom Class and extend them by boostrap classes , you should use grid system to make it easier , grid should look like this

```css
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1 class="text-center">TITLE</h1>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>left box</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <p>right box</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Remember about adding boostrap to your code ;)